# cURL and wget cannot resolve hosts, but apt-get works

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, wget, curl

I've installed Ubuntu server 16.04 in a VirtualBox. If I try to install software with apt-get it works fine, but `curl test.de` or `wget get.typo3.org/8.4.0` shows me that the host could not be resolved. The Adapter at the VirtualBox is NAT.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? You may need to set the `http_proxy` environment variable.

Comment: Is ping 8.8.8.8 working? What do you have in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: I had the same issue. I managed to solve it with this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349365/239064 I would post it as an answer but I'm really not sure what's going on so I'll just leave it as a comment here