# Ping works only with IP addresses (not with domain names)

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, ping

I assume this issue is to do with my DNS server, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am running Arch inside a Hyper-V virtual machine which is set up with a "Legacy Network Adapter" to my host's wireless network adapter.

When I run `ping 216.58.192.164`, an IP address for www.google.com, I get the following output and a successful ping (as expected):

`PING 216.58.192.164(216.58.192.164) 56(84) bytes of data.`

When I run `ping www.google.com`, I get the following output and 100% packet loss:

`Ping www.google.com(ord36s01-in-x04.ie100.net (2607::f8bo::4009::80c::2004)) 56 data bytes`

The internet connection on my host PC (running Windows 10) works just fine.

I have also noticed that the host PC has a different DNS server set. It is using Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, while the Arch virtual machine is using my ISP's (Time Warner Cable). However, even when I change to the Google DNS servers, the issue persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

When I run `ping 8.8.8.8`, I get the following output and a successful ping:

`PING 8.8.8.8(8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data`

When I run `nslookup stackexchange.com 8.8.8.8`, I get the following:

```
Server:        8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
```

Comment: Suggest you turn off ipv6.  And expand question to include output of `ping 8.8.8.8` and `nslookup stackexchange.com 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Or better still, turn **on** or otherwise fix ipv6, since it is obviously not working, even though the DNS is returning ipv6 addresses.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie and don't know how to do either of those things. Could you please be a bit more specific on how I would achieve this?

Comment: Please see my answer to this related question, and implement it. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308283/the-first-email-bounces-the-second-and-subsequent-emails-go-through

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

I have worked this out using Rui F Ribeiro's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308283/the-first-email-bounces-the-second-and-subsequent-emails-go-through).

I opened `/etc/gai.conf` and added the following to the last line:

`precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`

I then created a file at `/etc/sysctl.conf` and added `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` to the last line. I then ran `sudo sysctl -p`. Then everything worked perfectly.